# How to dtrace (or other method) library functions that were compiled with -fvisibility=hidden

Tags: visibility, dtrace

If I have a library that was compiled with

`-fvisibility=hidden`

and many of the functions are *not* exported, i.e. were not given this attribute in the code:

`__attribute__ ((visibility ("default")))`

Is there a way to use `dtrace` or any other utility to show trace output for the functions that were not exported?

With visible functions, I know you can do something like

`sudo dtrace -n 'pid$target::TheFunctionICareAbout:entry { trace(arg0); }' -p 12345`

Is there some similar way to get at those non-exported functions and show trace output? This presumes that I know the name of the function, say from reading the source or whatever.

Comment: I think maybe you can send mail to dtrace discussion mailing list(dtrace-discuss@lists.dtrace.org) to get help.